# Javascript substring check using indexOf or search on a date string with forward slash /

Tags: javascript, string, date

I am surprised to not to find any post regarding this, I must be missing something very trivial. I have a small JavaScript function to check if a string matches an object's properties. Simple stuff right? It works easily with all strings except those which contain a forward slash.

```
"‎04‎/‎08‎/‎2015‎".indexOf('4') // returns 2 :good
"‎04‎/‎08‎/‎2015‎".indexOf('4/') // returns -1 :why?
```

The same issue appears to be with .search() function as well. I encountered this issue while working on date strings.

Please note that I don't want to use regex based solution for performance reasons. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string has invisible Unicode characters in it. The "left-to-right mark" (hex 200E) appears around the two slash characters as well as at the beginning and the end of the string.

If you type the code in on your browser console instead of cutting and pasting, you'll see that it works as expected.

Comment: Interesting, I did actually copy pasted the strings into VisualStudio console window. I checked if I type the string on console like "04/".indexOf('4/'), then it gives the right result.

Then how do I get over the problem? I have a Date() object on which I call date.toLocaleString(). I wan't search on this string for substring. Do you suggest to get rid of invisible unicode characters generated before I use indexOf() method?

Comment: @lawc what platform gives you a string with those characters in it as a return value from `.toLocaleString()`? What locale are you in? My browser doesn't give me any special characters like that (in `en_US`).

Comment: I am on Windows platform and my locale is en-GB.

Comment: @lawc strange. Well you can use `date.toLocaleString().replace(/\u200E/g, "")` to remove the invisible characters.

Comment: I can confirm that after replacing the unicode character is is working as expected. However I am vary of using .replace() if it becomes an overhead. My method is going to be invoked on each keyboard stroke as it is part of search filter functionality.

I'll accept your answer as it solves the original issue, thank you for that. But I'll appreciate any further suggestions to improve substring search performance on string containing such invisible unicode characters.

Comment: @lawc well you could build a regular expression to allow for the possibility of those special characters. Or you could take a totally different approach and use the Date API to inspect the different parts of the date.