# indexOf returns -1 when string contains forward slash in Edge and IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Given the following variable:

```
var obj = "‎24‎/‎12‎/‎2017 ‎00‎:‎00 :: test :: £8.00 cancelRemove"
```

In IE11 and Edge (not Chrome or Firefox) the following code returns -1 when I expect the result to be 0:

```
obj.indexOf("24/12/2017")
```

This is breaking my Karma/Jasmine unit tests using the Chai assertion library and I can't fathom why.

Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656197/javascript-substring-check-using-indexof-or-search-on-a-date-string-with-forward)

I have invisible unicode characters in the string, apparently on IE / Edge only so I solved it with:

```
obj.toLocaleString().replace(/\u200E/g, "");
```